# Linear subspace addition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Consider two subspaces $L1,L2 \in R^3$,
Where basis of $L1$ is $(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$, and basis of $L2$ is $(0,1,0),(1,0,0)$, what is $L1+L2$?

Comment: $(0,1,1)$ will be the basis

Answer (score 1):

$$L_1 + L_2 = \{ v + w : v \in L_1, w \in L_2\}$$
Every element of $L_1$ can be written as a linear combination of $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Call these $e_2$ and $e_3$ respectively.

Similarly, every element of $L_2$ can be written as a linear combination of $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$. Let $(1,0,0) = e_1$

Thus we write $v = a_2 e_2 + a_3 e_3$ for some scalars $a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $w = b_1 e_1 + b_2 e_2$ for some scalars $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, we get $v + w = b_1 e_1 + (a_2+b_2)e_2 + a_3e_3$, and so every element of $L_1 + L_2$ can be written as a linear combination of the $e_i$.
Further, $e_i \in L_1 + L_2$ for each $i$, and the $e_i$ are linearly independent, so form a basis.

That is $$(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$$ is a basis for $L_1 + L_2 = \mathbb{R}^3$